# Format date with date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

Am trying to format date with such an example `2021-09-20T12:12:36.166584+02:00` with `date-fns` library but it doesn't work, what's the right approach ?

Below is my code :

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'
format(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: define 'doesn't work' please

Comment: Try to use lower case like `yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to parse your ISO string before you can format it, and use lowercase `dd` and `yyyy`:

```
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";

const dateFormatted = format(parseISO(date), "dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: why do we need to use lower case on `dd` and `yyyy` in here

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing see Jan Bouchner's answer below. date-fns handles the format options differently than does moment.js

Answer (score 2):

We definitely need more information on what the problem is.

But I guess you want to have a day of the month to be formatted so you should put **dd** instead of **DD**.

DD = 01, 02, ..., 365, 366

dd = 01, 02, ..., 31

And **yyyy** instead of **YYYY**.

And your input param *date* should be a type of Date:

```
format(new Date('2021-09-20T12:12:36.166584+02:00'), 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

Everything can be found in documentation (https://date-fns.org/v2.24.0/docs/format)

Comment: Warning - MDN strongly discourages using the `Date` constructor to parse date strings `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#timestamp_string